# How to Make Player Walk Up Hills in Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Hey guys so im making a 2D Platformer and ran into a difficult situation. Up until now I have had rectangular landscapes for the player to jump and walk on. Now I want to start adding some hills. Picture a triangle, the left side is representing a hill at which the player can walk up. Ive made the landscape as well as copied over the Box Collider 2D from my other paths. I figured out a way to rotate the collider so that it goes up at a 45 degree angle just like the slope of the triangle. For some reason though when I walk into the triangle the player doesnt start walking up it. I have to jump onto the hill and he lands on what looks like an invisible rectangle! I make the collider .25 in thickness so I know that I have the whole collider where I want it. Any idea why? I dont really have any code for this as everything Im doing has pretty much been in scene view. Thanks everyone!

Here is the Player in Play Mode, stands on top of hill by some force:

[image: Here is the Player in Play Mode, stands on top of hill by some force]

Here is what the collider looks like in scene view. Ive moved the collider all over and it still does the same thing:

[image: Here is what the collider looks like in scene view. Ive moved the collider all over and it still does the same thing]

Here is my movement code:

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

    public float maxSpeed = 3;
    public float speed = 50f;
    public float jumpPower = 150f;

    public bool grounded;

    private Rigidbody2D rb2d;
    private Animator anim;

    void Start () {

        rb2d = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
    }


    void Update () {

        anim.SetBool("Grounded",grounded);
        anim.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(rb2d.velocity.x));

        if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < -0.1)
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1);

        }
        if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0.1)
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);

        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && grounded)
        {
            rb2d.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpPower);

        }

    }

    void FixedUpdate() {

        Vector3 easeVelocity = rb2d.velocity;
        easeVelocity.y = rb2d.velocity.y;
        easeVelocity.z = 0.0f;
        easeVelocity.x *= 0.75f; 

        float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        //Fake friction / Easing the x speed of our player
        if (grounded)
        {

            rb2d.velocity = easeVelocity;


        }



        //Moving the Player
        rb2d.AddForce((Vector2.right * speed) * h);

        //Limiting the Speed of the Player
        if (rb2d.velocity.x > maxSpeed)
        {
            rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(maxSpeed, rb2d.velocity.y);

        }

        if (rb2d.velocity.x < -maxSpeed)
        {
            rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(-maxSpeed, rb2d.velocity.y);

        }
    }
}
```

The Ground Material is applied to this landscape just like the other rectangular landscape. Sorry Im new but again, thanks everyone!

Comment: It looks like You have another collider in that hill sprite object. Are You shure that there is only one? Could You share an image of inspector view of that asset?

Comment: Yeah I think it was the only one. Actually ditched it and started over. I took one of my rectangle platforms that I know work and just rotated it about 30 degrees. He can walk up it fine. I notice though that if I stop right before the hill and then walk, he goes up it a little slower, Im assuming this is a physics problem. Going down the slope he goes fast and does the "jump" animation as he slides down. Again, probably has to do with the physics. I may have to watch the videos that another user provided me here as I think this is a common occurrence in projects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Make Player Walk Up Slope in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44394190/how-to-make-player-walk-up-slope-in-unity)

Comment: @JosepValls instead of editing his original post, op chose to post a new one, the least op should do is delete the old one.

Comment: @Alox just saw that. Did OP use a different username?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should take a look at the [2D Plaftormer Controller tutorial series by Sebastian Lague](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLFt_AvWsXl0f0hqURlhyIoAabKPgRsqjz). The series is focused on creating a robust 2D platformer controller, and it is very well made. I have watched the videos and built a working solution based on them.

The [fourth episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cwcC2tIKObU&index=4&list=PLFt_AvWsXl0f0hqURlhyIoAabKPgRsqjz) of the series is focused on climbing slopes, and the next episode is focused on descending them. But I still suggest that you should start from the beginning and follow the series patiently. Lague always offers very detailed explanations to why he implements thing a certain way.

Answer (score -1):

I'm new to Unity as well but a thought I had was...is it possible your collider dimensions are resetting after the first frame? Maybe you can manually set the collider to stay at a certain angle to test this. Just a thought! I'd be interested to know what you find out.

Comment: Yeah the collider doesnt change throughout the frame. Actually ditched it and started over. I took one of my rectangle platforms that I know work and just rotated it about 30 degrees. He can walk up it fine. I notice though that if I stop right before the hill and then walk, he goes up it a little slower, Im assuming this is a physics problem. Going down the slope he goes fast and does the "jump" animation as he slides down. Again, probably has to do with the physics. I may have to watch the videos that another user provided me here as I think this is a common occurrence in projects.

Comment: Interesting....thanks for the update! I'll play around tonight and see what comes up:) Nice job figuring it out! And thanks to Hilse as well.

Comment: Just provide an adequate answer-format, give some basic steps to make sure you are giving a good answer, otherwise you better leave a comment. This kind of answer tend to receive down votes or flags by moderators. You can get 15 xp easily just asking some well received questions or giving some good answers to unlock comments, good luck!